# codeigniter replace controller name for 2 or more controller from url

Tags: codeigniter

I have many controllers but i want to hide some of controllers. Right now if i do it for 2 or more controllers only one is working.

For example:
This is my route exmaple

```
 $route['(:any)'] = 'dealer_cars/$1';
 $route['(:any)'] = 'dealer_boats/$1;
```

In the url i am removing dealer_cars and dealer_boats only to name of dealer in the url to be displayed

```
www.mywebsitename.com/car_dealer_name and      
www.mywebsitename.com/boat_dealer_name
```

When i am doing this both url going to same controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use and Edit These :
If dealer_cars and dealer_boats are two **methods** of for example main_controller Use :

```
$route['dealer_cars/(:any)'] = 'main_controller/dealer_cars/$1';
$route['dealer_boats/(:any)'] = 'main_controller/dealer_boats/$1;
```

If They are seperate **files** in some_folder and controller action is index methods of them, use :

```
$route['dealer_cars/(:any)'] = 'some_folder/dealer_cars/index/$1';
$route['dealer_boats/(:any)'] = 'some_folder/dealer_boats/index/$1;
```

and Finaly if You want Like This :

```
www.mywebsitename.com/car_test  => main_controller/dealer_cars/test
www.mywebsitename.com/car_mazda  => main_controller/dealer_cars/mazda
www.mywebsitename.com/boat_boat1  => main_controller/dealer_boats/boat1
www.mywebsitename.com/boat_boat2  => main_controller/dealer_boats/boat2
```

Use Something Like This :

```
$route['car_(:any)'] = 'main_controller/dealer_cars/$1';
$route['boat_(:any)'] = 'main_controller/dealer_boats/$1;
```

Comment: suppose if it is like this, www.mywebsitename.com/car_dealer_controller/car_dealer_name and www.mywebsitename.com/boat_dealer_controller/boat_dealer_name.. I want to remove both car_dealer_controller and boat_dealer_controller from URL. If i remove both are going to car_dealer_controller... @Mehrdad Amini

Comment: You Can Not Remove , Because There wil be a conflict on car controller and boat controller , I mean System Does not know pass argument to witch controller, I mean: www.domain.com/abcd/ will go to witch controller??